# How to make collisions in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a python game and I am not exactly sure how to make the enemy's and the player have collisions. Could someone show me a easy way to add collisions to multiple things efficiently. I want the enemy in my python game to collide with the player. Here is the code I use to move the enemy to the player. This code moves the enemy but the enemy does not collide with the player.

```
if self.canvas.coords(self.man)[0] > self.canvas.coords(Man1.man)[0]:
    self.canvas.move(self.man,-1,0)
if self.canvas.coords(self.man)[0] < self.canvas.coords(Man1.man)[0]:
    self.canvas.move(self.man,1,0)
if self.canvas.coords(self.man)[1] < self.canvas.coords(Man1.man)[1]:
    self.canvas.move(self.man,0,1)
if self.canvas.coords(self.man)[1] > self.canvas.coords(Man1.man)[1]:
    self.canvas.move(self.man,0,-1)
```

Comment: are you asking how to move two items on a canvas until they touch?

Comment: check [this](https://inventwithpython.com/chapter18.html) out

Comment: I am trying to make a item on the canvas stop when it collides with another item

Comment: @Crafterguy you need to show us the code you have so far, it is fairly difficult to show you how to "stop" the item on the canvas without knowing how it is moving in the first place.

Comment: How would I find the answer to this question without it being to broad

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [canvas.overlapping()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method) which returns all the items in a given rectangle. Just give it the x,y coordinates of one of your objects and see if the tuple returns more than one.

if you show us some code or give more details we might be able to better help you

Comment: Could you please provide a working and verifiable example of its usage?

Comment: I tried canvas.overlapping but it gave me this error:AttributeError: 'Canvas' object has no attribute 'overlapping'